# Pairwise correlation based on effect size values with missing values of some variables

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot, ggcorrplot

I have data with seven variables and I want to calculate pairwise correlation (also the significance level of each correlation). The data I have is the effect size of a treatment on these seven variables. -ve value shows inhibiting effects and +ve value promoting effects. The higher or lower the value is the higher or lower the inhibiting or promoting effect is on certain variables. Data also contain a large number of missing values, so in pairwise correlation, I want R to ignore the correlation if one or both of the variables missing the value.

Here is a sample dataset

```
set.seed(123)

# Create the dataset with effect sizes and missing values
mydata <- data.frame(
  Var1 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var2 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var3 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var4 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var5 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var6 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var7 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE)
)

# Set more than 50% missing values in each column
for (col in 1:7) {
  missing_indices <- sample(1:200, size = 101)
  mydata[missing_indices, col] <- NA
}
```

My question is "Is it possible to calculate pairwise correlation along with the significance level using effect size values in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cor.test()` which only uses the relevant data for the pair of observations.  Unlike `cor()` `cor.test()` works only for one `x` and one `y` at a time.  In the code below, I use `outer()` to run through all pairs of values.  I do this for both the correlation (stored in `r`) and its p-value (stored in `p`).  First, we make the data according to your specification.

```r
set.seed(123)

# Create the dataset with effect sizes and missing values
mydata <- data.frame(
  Var1 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var2 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var3 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var4 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var5 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var6 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Var7 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 200, replace = TRUE)
)

# Set more than 50% missing values in each column
for (col in 1:7) {
  missing_indices <- sample(1:200, size = 101)
  mydata[missing_indices, col] <- NA
}
```

Next, we can make the correlations and their p-values.

```r
r <- outer(
  1:ncol(mydata),
  1:ncol(mydata),
  Vectorize(function(x, y) cor.test(mydata[, x], mydata[, y])$estimate)
)
p <- outer(
  1:ncol(mydata),
  1:ncol(mydata),
  Vectorize(function(x, y) cor.test(mydata[, x], mydata[, y])$p.value)
)

round(r, 2)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
#> [1,]  1.00  0.03 -0.07 -0.01  0.15 -0.05 -0.09
#> [2,]  0.03  1.00  0.16  0.19 -0.05 -0.11 -0.07
#> [3,] -0.07  0.16  1.00 -0.37  0.04 -0.24 -0.17
#> [4,] -0.01  0.19 -0.37  1.00  0.18  0.18 -0.04
#> [5,]  0.15 -0.05  0.04  0.18  1.00  0.24 -0.14
#> [6,] -0.05 -0.11 -0.24  0.18  0.24  1.00  0.13
#> [7,] -0.09 -0.07 -0.17 -0.04 -0.14  0.13  1.00
round(p, 2)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#> [1,] 0.00 0.83 0.65 0.94 0.30 0.72 0.55
#> [2,] 0.83 0.00 0.33 0.19 0.78 0.46 0.63
#> [3,] 0.65 0.33 0.00 0.02 0.78 0.11 0.33
#> [4,] 0.94 0.19 0.02 0.00 0.21 0.25 0.81
#> [5,] 0.30 0.78 0.78 0.21 0.00 0.10 0.36
#> [6,] 0.72 0.46 0.11 0.25 0.10 0.00 0.38
#> [7,] 0.55 0.63 0.33 0.81 0.36 0.38 0.00
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The question you asked is not entirely one of mechanics.  As you can see, the operations for calculating pairwise correlations with p-values is not all that difficult.  The other part of your question is - does it make sense to calculate these values on variables that contain the effect size?  I suppose if the observations are the same (i.e., the rows represent the same observation for each effect size) then it could make sense to do this.  If you're looking for more advice about that part of your question, you would likely be better off posting it on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

---

#### Edit: Errors in correlations

In the comments the OP suggested that there were some pairs that were producing errors.  The problem with the actual use-case data (not the example data) is that there are two pairs of variables where there are only two observations.  This triggers an error in `cor.test()`.  To solve this, you could put a `try()` statement to catch the errors and then return a missing value if there was an error.  The code will generate errors, but those errors are absorbed by `try()` so the computation will continue.  The resulting `r` and `p` matrices will have some missing values where there were pairs of variables with too few values to calculate the correlation.

```r
mydata <- structure(list(SOM = c(NA, -2.87, NA, NA, NA, 21.6, 6.04, NA, 
NA, -14.17, -0.77, 25.21, 3.3, 39.99, 225.37, 11.01, 2.85, 3.59, 
3.3, 3.91, 8.23, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -2.6, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.09, -0.79, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
-1.59, -2.18, -4.63, NA, NA, 1267.92, 3.21, NA, -2.28, NA, 3.64, 
4.63, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.71, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, -0.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.57, 11.61, NA, 67.13, 84.4, 
NA, NA, NA), SOC = c(NA, NA, 1.39, 0.8, 0.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.33, 1.99, -0.75, 
91.54, 11.06, 49.46, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.3, 3.33, 2.64, 5.97, 
1.99, 15.42, NA, NA, NA, -0.68, 0, 0, -0.23, 0.23, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.25, 0.48, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3.89, 7.89, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), MBC = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.92, 1.4, 
1.45, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.81, 3.44, 
7.56, 1.36, 10.57, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.68, -0.05, -0.02, 0.33, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.71, 0, NA, NA, 6.15, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
6.4, 2.89, 3.62, -0.5, -1.49, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.63, NA, NA), 
aN = c(-0.05, 10.67, 1.45, 1.96, 4.25, 7.76, 9.06, NA, 2.51, 
NA, -3.44, 6.6, 2.61, 18.26, 258.89, -54.22, NA, 2.56, 6.51, 
3.82, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17.01, 9.15, 23.48, 5.22, -5.41, -9.54, 
-2.06, 3.34, -1.54, 3.58, 1.26, 3.48, 6.52, 1.14, 6.31, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.95, -3.5, -1.11, -26.92, -1.72, 
NA, 0.09, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.28, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 7.31, 0.16, 0.08, 3.04, 0.74, -0.41, 0.14, 4.91, 2.7, 
0.73, 4.41, -0.15, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14.93, 23.42, NA, NA, 
NA), SoilP = c(-0.54, -9.39, 0.3, 1.85, NA, 61.46, 39.68, 
NA, 0.94, -31.07, 4.25, 11.3, 10.45, 23.09, 136.85, 796.34, 
-6.65, NA, NA, NA, 0.64, NA, NA, NA, 1.14, 1.04, 4.51, 5.36, 
9.88, -2.68, -2.45, 0.84, 12.28, 6.69, 14.72, 0, 23.48, 2.5, 
-0.32, 1.01, -1.49, 7.7, 6.52, 0.63, -0.17, 2.07, -0.29, 
0.91, -2, NA, NA, 1.11, NA, NA, 93.33, NA, 8.36, 8.06, 1.24, 
2.98, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.9, 15.87, -1.08, 0.09, -1.86, 
-0.96, -0.77, 42.5, 1.15, 0.02, 2.11, 0.25, -0.06, NA, NA, 
NA, -1.69, 109.66, 161.08, NA, -1.24, -2.22), SoilK = c(-0.3, 
2.93, NA, NA, NA, 68.38, 24.01, NA, -1.31, -4.74, 1.84, 1.05, 
0.21, 0.49, 928.42, 397.98, -14.39, NA, NA, NA, 1.61, NA, 
NA, NA, -27.11, NA, -2.95, -4.83, -0.93, -7.12, -0.1, NA, 
1.21, 2.67, 2.14, 1.02, 5.46, 0.74, 3.05, 1.67, -0.22, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -1.95, -0.5, -0.22, -0.27, NA, NA, 0.48, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.79, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.83, 57.68, 
-2.28, 0.14, 0.07, -0.17, -0.13, 6.99, 1.96, 2.02, 2.82, 
7.12, 2.13, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.01, 132.41, NA, NA, NA), Ureases = c(NA, 
NA, -1.32, 0.49, NA, -1.74, 0, 13.84, NA, 9.09, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.89, 1.66, 3.16, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.09, 10.87, 40.6, 2.92, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.05, 0.35, 4, NA, NA, 4.89, 
NA, 3.61, NA, 15.26, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03, 1.76, 3.51, 2.55, 
1.63, NA, 3.04, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.2, 6.4, 4.84, NA, NA), ALP = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.51, -0.55, 26.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.13, 11.3, 0.9, 1.69, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.72, NA, 3.26, NA, 8.27, 
18.11, 27.81, NA, 7.39, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.71, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.4, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), pH = c(-0.56, 17.82, NA, NA, 2.53, 0.6, 
-0.46, NA, 2.4, 9.59, 1.42, NA, NA, NA, 2.54, -0.92, 8.7, 
2.69, 4.57, 3.38, 1.65, 0.43, 2.04, 3.47, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, -2.72, 10.42, -0.98, -1.12, -1.74, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, -0.51, 4.38, -0.87, 1.71, 0, NA, -2.1, -1.6, -0.31, 5.02, 
2.8, -5.68, 11.76, NA, 0, NA, -7.85, 2.18, -0.44, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.12, NA, 1.92, 1.2, 0.57, 0.9, 0.91, NA, 
-0.89, -1.75, -0.9, -1.13, -0.47, 2.67, NA, NA, 2.09, NA, 
0.19, NA, 0.33, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 87L), class = "data.frame")
```

```r
r <- outer(
  1:ncol(mydata),
  1:ncol(mydata),
  Vectorize(function(x, y) {
    tr <- try(cor.test(mydata[, x], mydata[, y]))
    if(inherits(tr, "try-error")){
      NA
    }else{
      tr$estimate
    }
}))
round(r, 2)
#>        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
#>  [1,]  1.00    NA  0.96  0.91 -0.03  0.09 -0.02 -0.16 -0.31
#>  [2,]    NA  1.00  0.68  0.62 -0.03 -0.90  0.85    NA -0.51
#>  [3,]  0.96  0.68  1.00  0.24  0.92  0.77  0.55  0.24 -0.50
#>  [4,]  0.91  0.62  0.24  1.00 -0.06  0.80 -0.10 -0.20  0.07
#>  [5,] -0.03 -0.03  0.92 -0.06  1.00  0.53 -0.15 -0.31 -0.10
#>  [6,]  0.09 -0.90  0.77  0.80  0.53  1.00 -0.23 -0.34  0.01
#>  [7,] -0.02  0.85  0.55 -0.10 -0.15 -0.23  1.00  0.16  0.39
#>  [8,] -0.16    NA  0.24 -0.20 -0.31 -0.34  0.16  1.00 -0.04
#>  [9,] -0.31 -0.51 -0.50  0.07 -0.10  0.01  0.39 -0.04  1.00
```

```r
p <- outer(
  1:ncol(mydata),
  1:ncol(mydata),
  Vectorize(function(x, y) {
    tr <- try(cor.test(mydata[, x], mydata[, y]))
    if(inherits(tr, "try-error")){
      NA
    }else{
      tr$p.value
    }
  }))

round(p, 2)
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#>  [1,] 0.00   NA 0.04 0.00 0.87 0.69 0.95 0.70 0.17
#>  [2,]   NA 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.93 0.00 0.15   NA 0.05
#>  [3,] 0.04 0.01 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.13 0.06 0.85 0.09
#>  [4,] 0.00 0.02 0.50 0.00 0.69 0.00 0.71 0.66 0.70
#>  [5,] 0.87 0.93 0.00 0.69 0.00 0.00 0.57 0.36 0.51
#>  [6,] 0.69 0.00 0.13 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.43 0.41 0.96
#>  [7,] 0.95 0.15 0.06 0.71 0.57 0.43 0.00 0.65 0.24
#>  [8,] 0.70   NA 0.85 0.66 0.36 0.41 0.65 0.00 0.93
#>  [9,] 0.17 0.05 0.09 0.70 0.51 0.96 0.24 0.93 0.00
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! With the given data, your codes worked perfectly and yielded what I was looking for. A couple of more questions, please. 
1. In the above example, 'cor.test' function do what correlation? "pearson", "kendall", "spearman" or any other?
2. When I used my own data, which is quite similar to the sample data I provided above, I got the following error:
 Error in cor.test.default(mydata[, x], mydata[, y]) : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector
Even though all me columns are numeric

Comment: @KhashiuRahman Look at `?cor.test` for the other available methods.  I think the three you mentioned are it, but check the help file to be sure.  2. Is it possible that one pair of variables has no values in common - when the pairwise deletion happens, there are no observations left?

Comment: @KhashiuRahman I updated the answer - the new code at the bottom should work.

Comment: Thanks, but resulted (p) and (r) have all and only the missing (NA) values :(

Comment: I think I am making some errors while importing the data because when I downloaded the sample data in Excel using ( write.xlsx(mydata, "exceldata.xlsx", colNames = TRUE, rowNames = FALSE) ) and imported it again, running the correlation codes gave the same error. On the other hand, when I didn't write the data and used as originally generated by our codes above, everything was smooth. I am importing the data by (mydata <- read_excel("Data_Khashi.xlsx")). Also tried in .txt file bu no success!

Comment: I change the updated code to include your data.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. Means a lot to me. Everything is fine now :)

Comment: Dave, is it possible to find the best model fit for linear regression and pairwise linear regression comparison using this data? Let's say the first variable (first column) is the dependent variable and the others are independent variables.

Comment: @SOF_helps what exactly do you mean?  You can't do a regression model of the first column on all the other columns at the same time because every observation is missing on at least one variable.

Comment: I'm interested in determining if there are any commands that can handle missing values (NAs) by ignoring them and performing regressions using only the available data. For instance, when conducting a regression analysis between column 1 and column 4, is it feasible for the command to consider only those rows where values are present in both column 1 and column 4? Given that column 1 represents the dependent variable, a similar approach would be beneficial when comparing column 1 with each of the other columns.

Comment: The `lm()` function does linear regression models.  It will automatically use list wise deletion when estimating the models - meaning it only uses the observations that have complete data on the variables in the model.  That said, comparing models that use different observations is usually considered bad practice.